# How to define an anchor in PagedList.Mvc "Htm.PagedListPager"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

When using the Nuget package Mvc.PagedList.Mvc, I see that a fresh page is rendered each time I select a new page. How is it possible to maintain the same position on the page when the page refreshes?

I am aware of a technique that in my mind is messy, which is to have a property in my view model which stores whether the Index action was called by the pager or by anything else (form submit or external link) and use jQuery to jump to the location on page load.  Not only is it messy, but the user sees an "ugly" jump each time a new page is called.  Is there a way that I can include an anchor in the "Html.PagedListPager" statement?

```
@Html.PagedListPager(list: Model.ApplicantTable,
     generatePageUrl: page => Url.Action(actionName: "Index",
    routeValues: new
    {
        page = page,
        SelectedCampus = Model.SelectedCampus,
        Area = "Applicants"
    }
))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My eyes were drawn to the outer function "PagedListPager" and so I missed the inner function "Url.Action". It dawned on me that I could add the anchor to the end of the "Url.Action".

```
@Html.PagedListPager(list: Model.ApplicantTable,
     generatePageUrl: page => Url.Action(actionName: "Index",
    routeValues: new
    {
        page = page,
        SelectedCampus = Model.SelectedCampus,
        Area = "Applicants"
    }) + "#Paging")
```

The screenstill jumps when the page renders and moves to the anchor, but at least the code is cleaner.